# Translating placeholder messages in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I have the following peace of code:

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Callback(groups={"group_2"})
 */
public function validateMapping(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if ($someRequirementConstraint)
    {
        $variable = 'my.placeholder.label'
        $context->buildViolation('my.string.label',['%placeholder%' => $variable])
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

And in validators.nl.yml

```
my.placeholder.label: Bathtub
my.string.label: The value: %placeholder% must be used once.
```

When I run this the  output is:

```
'The value: my.placeholder.label must be used once.'
```

I would like to have the label that is inserted into the placeholder to be translated as well. However I do not have access to the translator inside the callback function. Does anyone know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Get translator from container:

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');
```

and then translate your word:

```
$variable = $translator->trans('my.placeholder.label');
```

Comment: You cant do variable in variable, translator dont handle this type. The only way is to pass `$variable = 'Bathtub';`

Comment: `$this->get('translator');` is not available in my class. The class does not inherit from anything.